# treeview select only one parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

in my treeview I have many parents and children nodes, When a parent node get selected after it should expand and other parent nodes should be disabled .

My jquery is

```
$('.treecheck').on('click', function() {
     $('.hitarea').next('input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

html is

```
<ul class="treeview" id="grouptree">
<li class="expandable">
    <div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="1" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">one</span>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="16" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">11</span>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="21" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">12</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="expandable">
    <div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="2" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">two</span>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="last">
            <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="17" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="expandable">
    <div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="3" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">three</span>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="last">
            <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="18" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">3</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="last">
    <input type="checkbox" class="treecheck" value="15" name="Profile[groups][]" original-title=""><span class="checkboxtree">four</span>
</li>
```

fiddle link **http://jsfiddle.net/jSwxE/4/**

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: did not understand the exact problem. can you share jsfiddle also.

Comment: i tried above my jquery , i allow user to select only one parent node

Comment: I am not sure but may be you want something like this :- http://jsfiddle.net/Z3978/

Comment: but make sure it have any  child checkbox before disable :)

Comment: @MohitArora: post it as an answer.

Comment: hi mohit check the fourth option

Comment: try this one http://jsfiddle.net/xCLh5/

Comment: @DhanushBala add `expandable` class to last li